# Remove \xe2\x80\xa6 from string python

Tags: python, string, replace, ascii

I have a lot of txt files, and I need to replace some text on them. Almost all of them has this `non-ascii` character (I thought it was `"..."`, but  … is not the same)
I've tried with `replace()` but I cannot make it, I need some help!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to open the files then you will get all strings as `unicode`s, which are [much easier to handle](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Answer (score 2):

Use unicode type strings. For example,

```
>>> print u'\xe2'.replace(u'\xe2','a')
a
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that these characters are not valid `str`ing, they are `unicode`.

```
import re
re.sub(r'<string to repleace>','',text,re.U)
```

most other answers will work too